# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 45), found shape=(None, 46)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am using DNNs for my project and I meet an error as follows. The architecture is

```
NN_model = Sequential()
# input layer 
NN_model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer = 'normal', input_dim = X_train.shape[1], activation = 'relu'))
# hidden layers 
NN_model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
NN_model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
# output layer
NN_model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation = 'linear'))
# Compile the network :
NN_model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['mae'])
```

I then use the fit() method to train the train set.

```
NN_model.fit(X_train, y1_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 32, validation_split = 0.2)
```

It worked

```
Epoch 1/10
799/799 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0082 - mae: 0.0533 - val_loss: 0.0091 - val_mae: 0.0531
Epoch 2/10
799/799 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0080 - mae: 0.0520 - val_loss: 0.0090 - val_mae: 0.0518
Epoch 3/10
799/799 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0080 - mae: 0.0522 - val_loss: 0.0087 - val_mae: 0.0502
....
```

But when I validated for the test set `NN_model.evaluate(X_test, y1_test)`, I got the following error.

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1366, in test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1356, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1349, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.test_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1303, in test_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 263, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 45), found shape=(None, 46)
```

My data set has 45 features. I don't know why the last error appeared.

Any comments are highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Most likely your `X_test` array has an extra column, you need to check that.

Comment: I got it. I just made a stupid mistake. That's fine now. Thanks!